# Mysql queries are hanging

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL server. MySQL queries are hanging and it causes the service to not work properly.
Please look at the photo below:

[stucked mysql queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICkmv.jpg)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps the database is locked somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by increasing the "innodb_buffer_pool_size" value. RAM 32GB and innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20GB